# Получение информации о мониторах без WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо получать данные о количестве мониторов, а так-же о рабочей области каждого из них, иметь возможность получить вычислить монитор, на котором сейчас находится окно и сделать это *без подключения в проект WindowsForms*.

По этой тебе была [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/116886/), но я не могу понять, откуда мы получаем `DisplayDispatcher`. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: `сделать это без подключения в проект WindowsForms` почему?

Comment: @tym32167 проект собирается при помощи Costura.Fody, и на выходе получается один файл. Важен его размер.

Comment: Ну WPF и WinForms не встраиваются в ехе, а присуствуют как часть фреймворка в системе.

Comment: ну да, WinForms сборка лежит в GAC, потому вам локально не надо её копировать.

Comment: @vitidev спасибо за информацию, приму к сведению. Реализую пока на WF, но вопрос оставлю ради интереса, как можно сделать это без WF.

Comment: zanuda mode on: - WF - это [Workflow Foundation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation)

Comment: [Is there a WPF equaivalent to System.Windows.Forms.Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707176/312041)